# VBA Loop across one row to find a value that contains a cell and delete columns before that column

Tags: vba, excel

I need to check each cell in row 7 starting from C7 (C7, D7, E7, etc) and find a cell with a string value that contains a certain date (for example, "9/30/2017" in string "6/30/2017 to 9/30/2017") and delete ALL columns from column C to whatever column that the cell is in. How would I do this with VBA code? I am new to VBA and have tried everything that I could find. Thankful for any suggestions

My code:

```
Sub DeleteUnnecessaryColumns(specifiedWorksheet) 

Dim lastCol As Long 
lastCol = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[C1], SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column 

For i = 1 To lastCol 
    If InStr(Cells(7, 0), specifiedDate, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then 
        Columns(i).Delete 
    End If 
Next i 

End Sub
```

Comment: So if we find the date in column **F**, do you watn to delete **C** and **E** or **C, D, F**??

Comment: If date is in F7, I want to delete column C, D, E.

Comment: @activexplor3 If you post what you have accomplished this far, we will be happy to help you.

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: Sub DeleteUnnecessaryColumns(specifiedWorksheet)

    Dim lastCol As Long
    lastCol = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[C1], SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
    For i = 1 To lastCol
        If InStr(Cells(7, 0), specifiedDate, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            Columns(i).Delete
        End If
    Next i
        
End Sub

Comment: @activexplor3 I've added your code to your post - next time, edit your post with the code instead of adding a new comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few changes:

1. Use a `With` block to explicitly target the specified worksheet
2. Add a `.` before the `Cells` collection to explicitly link to the specified worksheet (through the `With` block)
3. Start the loop with the correct column index for Column C = 3 (`For i = 3` ...)
4. You missed the first argument to the `InStr` function: starting character (1 was assumed) [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/instr-function)
5. The second argument for `InStr` wasn't set to the `i` variable. This will now cycle through the values in each column
6. The loop would not stop once it found the search text. So I added an `Else` clause that exits the `For` loop once `specifiedDate` is found, preventing the script from deleting columns to the right of the target column.
7. `specifiedDate` was never passed to the Sub or declared so I added it as a parameter. You can also declare and set it within this procedure. If it's declared as a public variable, then delete the parameter.
8. The `.Find` method is only available to a range object, so I used a method available to cells instead
9. After a column is deleted, the indices for the remaining columns are reduced by one so the same must be done to the variables controlling the loop

It should now properly delete a column if the search text is not found in row 7 and will stop executing once the first match is found, leaving the remaining columns intact.

```
Sub DeleteUnnecessaryColumns(specifiedWorksheet, specifiedDate) 

Dim lastCol As Long
With specifiedWorksheet
    lastCol = .Cells(7, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For i = 3 To lastCol
        If InStr(1, .Cells(7, i), specifiedDate, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then 
            .Columns(i).Delete
            i = i - 1
            lastCol = lastCol - 1
        Else
            Exit For
        End If 
    Next i 
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! I have tried the code and I get an Object Required error on this line: lastCol = .Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[C1], SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column

Comment: See edit. The `.Find` method is for the `Range` object. That seemed like extra overhead so I converted to the common ctrl + shift + end method. This isn't always correct, but is a decent alternative.

Comment: The code seems to have deleted column C and stopped after that.

Comment: Was `specifieddate` found in Col D?

Comment: No, it is part of the string in cell AF7.

Comment: Do `For i = 3 to 35` does it delete everything up to AF and stop?

Comment: I was previously mistaken, it didn't delete column C and stop. It deleted a variety of seemingly random columns. The original sheet prior to me running the code had values in columns C to EQ. Now only columns C to CK have values. For i = 3 to 35, the result is the same.

Comment: Is there a way to check only every 29th cell starting from C7? If the date is not in C7, delete 29 columns (including C, up to but not including AF). Most of the cells in row 7 are blank, so maybe not every cell needs to be checked.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I forgot that you need to reset the indices after the column deletion, so it doesn't skip random columns as you were seeing.

Comment: If you want to check every 29th column, use `Step` in the `For` loop [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/fornext-statement). Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0):

Something like...  You need to call it from somewhere else, using syntax like `DeleteUnnecessaryColumns "Sheet1", "9/30/2017"`

```
Sub DeleteUnnecessaryColumns(specifiedWorksheet as worksheet, SpecifiedDate as string) 

dim r as range   ' set up a range for row 7, columns C to the end
set r = specifiedWorksheet.rows(7)
set r = r.resize(Columnsize:= r.columns.count - 2)
set r =  r.offset(0,2)

Dim lastCol As Long, i as long

for i = 1 to r.columns.count  'loop through the cells in the r range
    if instr(string:=r.cells(i), substring:= SpecifiedDate) > 0 then
        lastcol = i  'this ends the loop and sets the value for lastcol
    end if 
next

SpecifiedWorksheet.range(cells(1, 3), cells(1, lastcol - 1).entirecolumn.delete

End Sub
```